# Convert String to SocketAddr

Tags: rust

In versions of Rust before 1.0, I was able to use `from_str()` to convert a `String` to `SocketAddr`, but that function no longer exists. How can I do this in Rust 1.0.?

```
let server_details = reader.read_line().ok().expect("Something went wrong").as_slice().trim();

let server: SocketAddr = from_str(server_details);

let mut s = BufferedStream::new((TcpStream::connect(server).unwrap()));
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`from_str` was renamed to [`parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) and is now a method you can call on strings:

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;

fn main() {
    let server_details = "127.0.0.1:80";
    let server: SocketAddr = server_details
        .parse()
        .expect("Unable to parse socket address");
    println!("{:?}", server);
}
```

If you'd like to be able to **resolve DNS entries** to IPv{4,6} addresses, you may want to use [`ToSocketAddrs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html):

```
use std::net::{TcpStream, ToSocketAddrs};

fn main() {
    let server_details = "stackoverflow.com:80";
    let server: Vec<_> = server_details
        .to_socket_addrs()
        .expect("Unable to resolve domain")
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", server);

    // Even easier, if you want to connect right away:
    TcpStream::connect(server_details).expect("Unable to connect to server");
}
```

`to_socket_addrs` returns an iterator as a single DNS entry can expand to *multiple* IP addresses! Note that this code won't work in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) as network access is disabled there; you'll need to try it out locally.

Answer (score 10):

I'll expand on "if you want to connect right away" comment in Shepmaster's answer.

Note that you don't really need to convert a string to a `SocketAddr` in advance in order to connect to something. `TcpStream::connect()` and other functions which take addresses are defined to accept an instance of `ToSocketAddr` trait:

```
fn connect<T: ToSocketAddr>(addr: T) -> TcpStream { ... }
```

It means that you can just pass a string to `connect()` without any conversions:

```
TcpStream::connect("stackoverflow.com:80")
```

Moreover, it is *better* not to convert the string to the `SocketAddr` in advance because domain names can resolve to multiple addresses, and `TcpStream` has special logic to handle this.

Comment: The string is a host:port combo from stdin. The address would change each time. I'm quite sure it needs to be converted.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You don't need to call `to_socket_addr()` manually when you just want to connect to something. And what do you mean about address changing each time?

Comment: @vladimir-matveev ToSocketAddr expects (among other things) Name:Port or Address:Port when converting strings "www.example.com".to_socketaddr "192.168.0.1:80".to_socketaddr "192.168.0.1:80".to_socketaddr

Answer (score 1):

In clap, you can parse like this:

```rust
    #[derive(Clone, Debug, Parser)]
    #[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
    struct Args {
        #[arg(long, env, default_value = "demo.com:8080", value_parser = resolve_host)]
        target_host: SocketAddr,
    }
        
    fn resolve_host(hostname_port: &str) -> io::Result<SocketAddr> {
        let socketaddr = hostname_port.to_socket_addrs()?.next().ok_or_else(|| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::AddrNotAvailable,
                format!("Could not find destination {hostname_port}"),
            )
        })?;
        Ok(socketaddr)
    }
```