# Into<SocketAddr> for String

Tags: rust, types, rust-warp

I'm trying to give a `String` to the `warp::server().run()` function as the listening address. But I do not know how to impl `Into<SocketAddr>` for String.

Code

```
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // GET /hello/warp => 200 OK with body "Hello, warp!"
    let hello = warp::path!("hello" / String)
        .map(|name| format!("Hello, {}!", name));

    warp::serve(hello)
        .run("127.0.0.1:3030")
        .await;
}
```

Error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::net::SocketAddr: From<&str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/server/mod.rs:24:29
   |
24 |         warp::serve(routes).run("127.0.0.1:3030").await;
   |                             ^^^ the trait `From<&str>` is not implemented for `std::net::SocketAddr`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::net::SocketAddr as From<(I, u16)>>
             <std::net::SocketAddr as From<SocketAddrV4>>
             <std::net::SocketAddr as From<SocketAddrV6>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<std::net::SocketAddr>` for `&str`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String to SocketAddr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255861/convert-string-to-socketaddr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion from a `&str` or `String` into a `SocketAddr` is fallible, e.g. `""` cannot be mapped to a valid `SocketAddr`.

Thus you need to use a fallible conversion to obtain a type that implements `Into<SocketAddr>`, one such type is `SocketAddr` itself. You can convert a `&str` to a `SocketAddr` through `FromStr` or `TryFrom` which enable you to write `"127.0.0.1:3030".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap()`.

Another option is changing the way you pass your address data to the `run()` method, e.g. `([u8;4], u16)` should implement direct conversion since the type constrains it to valid `SocketAddr`s.